# ¿Existe alguna palabra para calificar a algo que genera ansiedad?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Supongamos que existe una situación, un lugar, o lo que fuere que genere ansiedad. ¿Cómo se lo llamaría?. Por ejemplo, una sustancia que genera adicción es adictiva. ¿Cómo sería el equivalente para ansiedad?

¿Existe alguna palabra para calificar a algo que genera ansiedad?

Comment: Posiblemente _alarmante_ or _inquietante_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El término más correcto para “algo que genera ansiedad” es *ansiógeno*. El mismo no se encuentra en el DLE, pero [la propia RAE lo considera](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1237383458680451072) “bien formado”. Es un término técnico, [propio de la psiquiatría y la psicología](https://dicciomed.usal.es/palabra/ansiogeno-na), que se emplea por oposición a *ansiolítico*.

[image: ansiógeno]

En el uso común, sin embargo, no hay ninguna palabra habitualmente usada para este concepto, de manera que hay que emplear derivados de sinónimos de *ansia* o *ansiedad* o simplemente decir de algo “que genera ansiedad”.

Comment: Que hallazgo ese tweet